# Failed to resolve: com.github.Q42:AndroidScrollingImageView:1.3.2 error

Tags: android, image, scroll, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using android studio 3.1.2, my app gradle is given below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ajay.pocketassistance"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Q42:AndroidScrollingImageView:1.3.2'

}
```

And my project gradle is as given below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I sync gradle, it throws error as given below:

> Failed to resolve: com.github.Q42:AndroidScrollingImageView:1.3.2

I checked [github repo](https://github.com/Q42/AndroidScrollingImageView/issues/4) for solution, couldn't find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **project level** `build.gradle`:

Add this:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Hope your problem will be solve.

For better understanding, check the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Then it's exactly not for your gradle setting, It's worked for me. I already checked this out.

Comment: What is the `minsdkversion` in your gradle? Can this library support API level 27?

Comment: Resolved it, I removed `maven {https://maven.google.com}` and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Edit your answer and I can vote it up, my vote is locked. But I've accepted your answer

Comment: and congratulations! Happy coding.

Comment: Voted up! Thanks